# MATLAB : Trim the zeros in the arrays and concatenate variable dimension columns to from a matrix

Tags: matlab, strcat

The output of my code is as follows

```
load(1).value(1:end) = [0.0100 0.5030 0.7590 1]

load(2).value(1:end) = [0 0 0 0 1]

load(3).value(1:end) = [0 0 0 0 0 0.2000 0.4000]
```

But I want

```
load(1).value(1:end) = [0.0100 0.5030 0.7590 1]

load(2).value(1:end) = [1]

load(3).value(1:end) = [.2000 0.4000]
```

How can I trim the "leading zeroes, that occur from load(2)" away and later concatenate these array's vertically together in xlsx or csv format?

the csv file should contain:'0.0100 0.5030 0.7590 1' in 1st column, '1' in second column and '.2 .4' in third column

Comment: Just the leading zeros?

Comment: The column position of the data is not important then? So for the example above, could you edit in the `csv` format you want in the end?

Comment: the zeros are to do with how matlab displays things. once you export to csv they will disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save those values in a intermediate array you could select the index equal to zero and delete them.

```
aux=[0.0100 0.5030 0.7590 1]
aux(aux==0)=[];
load(1).value(1:end) = aux;

aux=[0 0 0 0 1]
aux(aux==0)=[];
load(2).value(1:end) = aux;

aux=[0 0 0 0 0 0.2000 0.4000]
aux(aux==0)=[];
load(3).value(1:end) = aux;
```

For the concatenation, check [vertcat()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html), for vertical concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that matches your number example. Though I feel that if you want to write to csv or xls it is best to do this before messing up the shape by removing zeros.

A simple way to get all nonzero elements:

```
[~, ~, load(1).value] = find(load(1).value);
```

Comment: [~, ~, load(2).value(1:end)] = find(load(2).value(1:end));

In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B
must be the same.

Comment: @user3734298 Can't reproduce this when I start with: `clear, load=struct(); load(2).value = [0 0 0 0 1]` However, I have reduced the code somewhat, perhaps eliminating the cause of the problem.